# OpenGL Rendering Triangles with Positive Z-Values

Tags: c++, opengl

It's my understanding that in NDC, the OpenGL "camera" is effectively located at (0,0,0), facing down the negative Z-axis. Because of this, **anything with a positive Z-value should be behind the view, and not visible**. I've seen this idea reiterated on multiple tutorials about coordinate systems in OpenGL.

I recently modified an orthographic renderer I've been working on to use proper GLM matrices instead of doing a bunch of separate addition and multiplication operations on each coordinate. I had previously been normalizing Z-values between 0 and -1, as I had believed this was the visible range.
However, when I was troubleshooting problems with the matrices, I noticed that **triangles appeared to be rendering onscreen even when the final Z-values (after all transformations) were positive**.

To make sure I wasn't forgetting about a transformation at some stage that re-normalized Z-values to the (0, -1) range, I tried forcing the Z-value of every vertex to a specific positive value (0.9) in the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 svp; //sprite-view-projection matrix

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 colorIn;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoordsIn;
out vec4 color;
out vec2 texCoords;

void main()
{
    vec4 temp = svp * vec4(position, 1.0);
    temp.z = 0.9;
    gl_Position = temp;
    //gl_Position = svp * vec4(position, 1.0);
    color = colorIn;
    texCoords = texCoordsIn;
}
```

To my surprise, everything is rendered anyway.

[image: Screenshot of program]

Using a constant Z-value of -0.9 produces identical results. If I change the constant value in the vertex shader to be greater than or equal to 1.0, nothing renders. It's almost as if the camera is located at (0,0,1) facing down the negative Z-axis.

I'm aware that matrices can effectively change the location of the camera, but only through transformations on the vertices. If I set the z-value to be positive in the vertex shader, after all transformations, shouldn't it definitely be invisible?

I've gotten the renderer to work more or less as I intended with matrices, but this behavior is confusing and challenges my understanding of the OpenGL coordinate system(s).

Comment: "*I've seen this idea reiterated on multiple tutorials about coordinate systems in OpenGL.*" Are you sure you aren't confusing their discussion of NDC space with camera-space?

Comment: @Scheff Good idea, but I'm using an orthographic projection, so I believe the W coordinate remains 1.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I understand correctly. The coordinates exiting the vertex shader are in NDC space, and in NDC space, only negative Z values are visible (because of the camera's position at (0,0,0) ), right?

Comment: NDC -> Normalized Device Coordinates. IMHO, all three dimensions have a range of [-1, 1]. (I google a bit to see whether I remember right...)

Comment: Found it: [Learn OpenGL - Coordinate Systems](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) _OpenGL expects all the vertices, that we want to become visible, to be in normalized device coordinates after each vertex shader run. That is, the x, y and z coordinates of each vertex should be between -1.0 and 1.0; coordinates outside this range will not be visible._

Comment: @DragonOfAwesome: "*I think I understand correctly.*" Then show me a tutorial that says those things. That says specifically what you're claiming about NDC space. Also, what exits the VS are in clip-space, not NDC space.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm sorry, obviously my ideas about NDC space/clip-space are confused. Are positive z-values in NDC-space visible on the screen? I can't really find a straight answer, despite combing dozens of pages. [This page](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) says that you can think of your screen as "being the center of the 3 axes and the positive z-axis going through your screen towards you, which suggests that only negative values would be "into" the screen, and visible. Am I just misunderstanding things?

Comment: Page 80 of "OpenGL Distilled" says "For geometry to be visible in a standard perspective projection, it must lie somewhere along the negative z axis in eye coordinates. Geometry along the positive z axis is behind the viewpoint and, therefore, is not rendered." Eye space is another term for camera space, right? I'm not sure this applies since it mentions a perspective projection and eye space, but if the "camera" is located at (0,0,0) when no transformations are applied, and it faces the negative z-axis, would positive values still be visible?

Comment: [Here's another page](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/calculating-the-gluperspective-matrix-and-other-opengl-matrix-maths/) suggesting such: "What I find strange about the OpenGL coordinate system is the orientation of Z. Since the positive Z axis runs towards the camera, it means that every visible object in the scene needs to have a negative z coordinate, which seems a bit un-intuitive."

Comment: @DragonOfAwesome: All of them are talking about camera space, not NDC space. They don't say that very well, but it's clear that they are.